# Tabhost and ViewPager not showing Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

I have a little problem with my tabs, I have a Fragment extended class which has a Tabhost. In the tabs I want to show another fragments and at the same time use the ViewPager to change from one fragment to another.

My problem is that the tabhost is not showing anything, but if I do a println of the content that is suposse to be showing I get the correct information.

I don't know what else to do.

Here is my code for the class with the tabhost:

```
public class PerfilEstructuraFragment extends Fragment implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

private ImageView imvFotoPerfil;
private static Context cd;
private static Resources res;
private TabHost mTabHost;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, PerfilEstructuraFragment.TabInfo>();
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
/**
 *
 * @author  
 * Maintains extrinsic info of a tab's construct
 */
private class TabInfo {
     private String tag;
     private Class<?> clss;
     private Bundle args;
     private Fragment fragment;
     TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
         this.tag = tag;
         this.clss = clazz;
         this.args = args;
     }

}
/**
 * A simple factory that returns dummy views to the Tabhost
 * @author  
 */
class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
     */
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }

}
/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Inflate the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil_estructura);
    // Initialise the TabHost
    this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
    }
    // Intialise ViewPager
    this.intialiseViewPager();
}*/

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_perfil_estructura, container, false);

    cd = getActivity();

    res = getResources();


    // Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = cd.getSharedPreferences(Config.getPreferencias(), 0);
    String idUsuario = settings.getString(Config.getIdVisitante(), null);
    //Si el identificador del usuario en nulo eso significara que no estamos visitanto el perfil de nadie, ergo, estamos visitando el nuestro

    //Si por algun motivo no ha podido conseguir a ID del usuario, no cargamos nada
    if(idUsuario==null){
        return rootView;
    }

    imvFotoPerfil = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imvFotoPerfil);

    imvFotoPerfil.setTag(Amigo.dummyFriends().get(Integer.parseInt(idUsuario)).getFotoPerfil());
    DownloadImageTask img = new DownloadImageTask();
    img.descargarImagen(imvFotoPerfil);


    this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState, rootView);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
    }
    else{
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
    // Intialise ViewPager
    this.intialiseViewPager(rootView);

    return rootView;

}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //save the tab selected
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}*/

/**
 * Initialise ViewPager
 */
private void intialiseViewPager(View rootView) {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(cd, PerfilInformacionFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(cd, PerfilInformacionFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(cd, PerfilInformacionFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(cd, PefilListaAlbumesFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(cd, PerfilInformacionFragment.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getFragmentManager(), fragments);
    //this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    //
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

/**
 * Initialise the Tab Host
 */
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args, View rootView) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    /*LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager((Activity) cd, false);
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(args);
    mTabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
    */
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    PerfilEstructuraFragment.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, 
                        this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(res.getText(R.string.tab_infomacionGeneral)),
                        ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", PerfilInformacionFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    PerfilEstructuraFragment.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, 
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator(res.getText(R.string.tab_actividades),  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_user_perfil)),
            ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", PerfilInformacionFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    PerfilEstructuraFragment.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, 
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator(res.getText(R.string.tab_amigos),  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_user_perfil)),
            ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", PerfilInformacionFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    PerfilEstructuraFragment.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, 
                this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator(res.getText(R.string.tab_album),  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_user_perfil)),
                ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab4", PefilListaAlbumesFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);


    PerfilEstructuraFragment.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, 
                this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab5").setIndicator(res.getText(R.string.tab_tablon),  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_user_perfil)),
                ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab5", PerfilInformacionFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);


    //PerfilEstructuraFragment.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", Tab3Fragment.class, args)));
    //this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    // Default to first tab
    //this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
    //
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

/**
 * Add Tab content to the Tabhost
 * @param activity
 * @param tabHost
 * @param tabSpec
 * @param clss
 * @param args
 */
private static void AddTab(PerfilEstructuraFragment activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(cd));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener#onTabChanged(java.lang.String)
 */
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    //TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrolled(int, float, int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
        int positionOffsetPixels) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected(int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    System.out.println(position);
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

And here is the XML I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#93EC83" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imvFotoPerfil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundcolor"
        android:contentDescription="@string/estruc_icono"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#476644" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </TabWidget>

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Can you provide the layout xml please?

Comment: Try to not wrap the `ViewPager` in the `FrameLayout` that you designate as the content part.

Comment: @Luksprog I don't understand you very well. When you say "warp", what do you mean? The Framelayout and the ViewPager object are together, no one is warping the other, or I have a big confusion...

Comment: Sorry about that, due to the poor xml formatting it appeared that you wrapped the `ViewPager` in the `FrameLayout`. You're not passing the proper `FragmentManager` to your adapter, it should be `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Ok, I have changed to `getChildFragmentManager`, but there is no change.
I have looking and I've found that I should use `FragmentTabHost` instead `TabHost`, I don't understand if there is any difference, but I'll try.

Comment: Do you at least see the tabs? And please use the @user notation so I can get notified about replies.

Comment: Sorry @Luksprog, I'm new here so I don't control this as I would like. When I execute it I can see the tabs, and in the LogCat the println result

Comment: The `FrameLayout` with the id `@android:id/tabcontent` has its height set to `match_parent`. You probably want to use a value of 0.

Comment: Oh God I love you @Luksprog!! It has been as you've said, I have set in the XML ' android:layout_height="0dp"' and suddenly everything has been solved! I could see the content, change it with the tab or sweeping the content. Thank you so much!!!